# Как создать Agularjs выпадающий список <select> который возвращает значение переменной

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

Создаю калькулятор подсчета оплаты за страховку.
Не могу разобраться как создать выпадающий список который возвращает значение в переменную.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="opts.val1" >
  <option ng-value="true">Bezszkodowe ubezpieczenie - żniżka 5%</option>
  <option ng-value="false">Wystąpienie szkody w okresie ubezpiczenie - zwyżka 8%</option>
</select>
<br>
<select ng-model="opts.val2">
  <option ng-value="true">Płatność jednorazowa - żniżka 2%</option>
  <option ng-value="false">Płatność w 4 ratach - zwyżka 4%</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$scope.opts = function() {
  return val1;
  return val2;
};

$scope.computedTotal = function() {
  var opts = $scope.opts;

  if (opts.val1 === true && opts.val2 === true) {
    return $scope.ins = Math.ceil($scope.basPremium * 0.93);
  } else if (opts.val1 === true && opts.val2 === false) {
    return $scope.ins = Math.ceil(($scope.basPremium * 0.95) * 1.04);
  } else if (opts.val1 === false && opts.val2 === true) {
    return $scope.ins = Math.ceil(($scope.basPremium * 0.98) * 1.08);
  } else if (opts.val1 === false && opts.val2 === false) {
    return $scope.ins = Math.ceil($scope.basPremium * 1.12);
  }
};
```